# ARKit - How to make object look at me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

How can I make an object to be facing at me when placed on the surface with ARKit (Unity, C#).

I tried myObject.transform.LookAt(MainCamera), but in this case the object is rotated in wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you aren't passing the correct WorldUp vector to the LookAt() function, but I find that LookAt() never really gives the desired effect, so I always do this instead:

```
var rotationAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation ( targetPosition.position - transform.position);
//Declare damp at the top and set it to something like 5.0
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp ( transform.rotation, rotationAngle, Time.deltaTime * damp)
```

If you don't want to smooth the rotation, and you would rather it "snap" to the desired rotation, then just remove the Quaternion.Slerp.